# How do native speaker understand suffix-forming nouns?

Tags: suffixes

Even if native speakers who know what 'require' mean, if they meet this noun and adjective first 'requirement' and 'requisite', don't know what they mean exactly? and have to search the words in a dictionary?

Also in this case the verb 'apply' it is related to a few noun-forming words, such as application , appliance, and applicant, native speakers have to browse the words to know what they mean definitely?

Anyway, in my opinion, English speakers might have learned noun forms of verbs one by one at times they have heard a word, talking with people.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right that a lot of words are learned one by one as they're heard, usually in childhood. It's also common to look up a word in a dictionary if the meaning is unknown and can't be discerned from context. However, one of the more common ways English-speakers will draw a connection between say "requirement" and "requisite" is both through recognizing the shared etymology (or guessing at it) and through interpreting the word as its used in context, whether that's in writing or in speech. This can occasionally lead to mistakes, but it works most of the time.